# Some doubts on kernel building

Tags: linux-kernel, android-kernel

I was trying to build a kernel for my android device. I would have used my Linux system for building a kernel but unfortunately it had its hdd failed. So I am now using Windows 10 WSL for building the kernel. I am really new in building kernel and I have a few doubts:

1. When I tried to use `arm-linux-gnueabihf 4.7` for making clean I got this error:

   ```
   ccache execv 'my toolchain path' execv format error
   ```

   I tried it with few other toolchains but same error came. Then I used `arm-eabi 4.8` which worked correctly. This solved the problem but I would like to know what the error was and what caused it and is there a fix?
2. How should I know what toolchain I should use for building kernels like some people tell me to use a toolchain some people tell me to use someother toolchain.
3. When I tried to build the kernel with `arm-eabi 4.8` I got an error

   ```
   /home/inkiluz/kernel/security/tima_uevent/tima_uevent.c:217:1: fatal error: opening dependency file security/tima_uevent/.tima_uevent.o.d: No such file or directory
    module_exit(tima_uevent_exit);
    ^
   compilation terminated.
   ```

   Is this a toolchain error or did i do something wrong? How can I rectify this?

   Here is the the error log: https://del.dog/diwijegetu.

Please do help me out...

Comment: Message "makefile:130 error 2" is not such informative: it just tells that *some* error has been occured **before**. It should be a message describing *actual* error somewhere above in the build log (before the lines you show us). For being able to help you, we need to see that actual error message.

Comment: Oh thanks i have posted the build log above in dogbin link

Comment: At the line 3 of your log you have a fatal error: "/home/inkiluz/kernel/security/tima_uevent/tima_uevent.c:217:1: fatal error: <...>". For the debugging purposes, the lines after that error are secondary. Please, [edit] your question and add this error message into it. It is a rule of Stack Overflow that the error message should be **in the question post**; links are not saticfy for that requirement. (When edit, you may remove from the question post the message `makefile:130 error 2`: according to the error log, this is not even an actual message, and may only confuse other readers).

Comment: ok i edited the post

Comment: First, disable ccache. Second, br sure you set correct ARCH and CROSS_COMPILE environment variables.

Comment: I will try and get back to you @0andriy

Comment: still no even after disabling ccache @0andriy